# Lua Closures in implementing a DSL

Tags: function, lua, dsl, closures, parentheses

Lua has a really nice no-parenthesis call syntax that coupled with function closures allow me to write the following

```
local tag = 1
function test(obj)
    return 
        function(str)
            return 
            function (tbl)
                tbl.objtag = tag
                tbl.objname = str
                return tbl
            end
        end

end
test (tag) "def"
{
}

test tag "def" --error
{
}
```

However, if I remove the parenthesis around (tag), it results in a compile error. So why does Lua allow no-parenthesis parameters (i.e. "def") and not no-parenthesis var (table in this case) parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html):

> If the function has one single argument and this argument is either a literal string or a table constructor, then the parentheses are optional:

My understanding of your above situation is that tag is a local variable (which is neither a literal string nor a table constructor), so `test(tag)` always requires parentheses.  You *don't* need parentheses around `"def"` because `test(tag)` returns a function which accepts a single string, and that function is immediately applied to `"def"`.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't run the input to the DSL through some sort of "preprocessor" to put parentheses around everything?

Comment: This has come up in the mailing list a couple of times. It usually starts by wondering why literal numbers aren't included. IIRC, there are parsing edge cases where the benefits to some don't outweigh the costs to everyone else. The benefits in the case of table c-tors and literal strings are pretty clear, especially in the early Lua use-case of data description languages.